# Wanting 1 output vs multiple in loops

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, nested

I am writing a function that takes a 'major' and iterates it through the values in the dictionary. The correct output is if the major is in the value print the key (1 instance) and if it is not just print the 'major' as upper(). But I cannot figure out how to write it as such that it checks each value, but only prints one instance of the key if the value is in it, and not multiple uppercase formats for the other 16 values.

**Input:**
education,
comp sci

**Output:**
EDUCATION,
COMP

```
student_majors_vari = {
'COMP':['compsci','comp sci','computer sci','computer science'],
'CMPE':['compeng', 'comp eng', 'computer eng', 'computer engineering'],
'EE':['eleceng', 'elec eng', 'elec engineering', 'electrical engineering'],
'MATH':['mathsci', 'math sci', 'mathematical sci', 'mathmatical sciences', 'mathematics']
}

def get_major_code(major):
  for univ_majors in student_majors_vari:
    values = student_majors_vari[univ_majors]
    for v in values:
        if major == v or major == values:
            print(univ_majors)
        else:
            print(major.upper())
```

Comment: Please provide an example output

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `dict.items()` method to loop through the key/value pairs and then the `in` operator to see if the `major` is in the `values` list. Also, I would `return` the value from the function to stop the loop and prevent duplicates.

Here's the pseudocode:

```py
def get_major_code(major):
    # Loop through .items() of the dict
        # Check if the major is in the values list
            # If so, return the univ_majors
            # Otherwise, return the major.upper()
```

This seems like a HW assignment, so see if you can do it from that description.

Comment: I've updated it and gotten it to print a single output like I need it to, but it only works for the values for COMP. The rest of the values for the other keys returns the else-loop.          
                                                                                                                                               `for univ_majors, values in student_majors_vari.items():
        if major in values:
            return print(univ_majors)
        elif major in univ_majors:
            return print(univ_majors)
        else:
            return print(major.upper()`

Comment: Why do you have an `elif`? There are only two conditions, right? Something is either in the majors or it isn't. What else is there to compare?

Comment: I had my conditions wrong! I don't need the elif! Thanks